# Trigger touch event in UIButton embedded in UIScrollView while scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, touch-event

I have a UIScrollView with a group of UIButtons embedded in it.  When the UIButtons receive any sort of touch event (while the UIScrollView isn't scrolling) I have them perform an animation that looks like they are being pressed.  However, when the UIScrollView is scrolling, the touch event actions of the UIButtons are not triggered.  I have attempted to set the zPosition on the UIButtons above the UIScrollView and I have also tried to pass the touch event from the UIScrollView to the UIButton in the same CGRect, but neither of these approaches worked. Let me know what you got...

Comment: have set selector for UIbutton's added in UIscrollview

Comment: I am setting a selector for the UIButtons on all touch events, the issue is that they do not receive a touch event when the UIScrollView is scrolling.

Comment: The question is: why would you want the buttons to work while the scroll view is scrolling? That would be a very confusing user experience. Is it some kind of game that you want the user to try to hit the buttons while they are moving?